# How can I find a memory leak of a running process?

Tags: c, debugging, memory-leaks

Is there a way, I can find the memory leak of a running process? I can use Valgrind for finding memory leaks before the start of a process. I can use GDB to attach it to a running process. How could I debug a memory leaks of a running process? Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36450/17720

Comment: Any reason in particular why you can't use Valgrind? Just curious.

Comment: Well, if a process is already running, is there a way I can attach it?

Comment: I meant, why do you have to attach it to a running process? I.e. why not just run the process with Valgrind?

Comment: For Example, if you are running a simulaton which takes hours, then u can stop it and run it again..... or else if you have a process which is already running, then u can't stop and check.... u can debug by attaching gdb, but with memory leaks

Answer (score 3):

Profilers instrument the code.. hence you must run your app 'through' them.  I would say you are in trouble if you cannot figure it out with gdb, and if you can't create a new instance for some reason and test with a profiler.

Comment: Is there a way to find memory leaks with gdb?

Comment: You can inspect the values of variables.  So, it would be like finding a needle in a haystack unless your app is small or you have strong suspicions and have a targeted search.  So its technically possible to find it, but by no means will gdb spell anything out for you and likely isn't practical.